# JTextField Array issue

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtextfield, grid-layout

So I'm working with a two-dimensional array of JTextFields for a Sudoku program.

```
public JTextField[][] userInputArray = new JTextField[9][9];
```

Now. I'm getting a continual null pointer exception, and can't discern how to fix it. It comes from firing this method:

```
    public void showTextFields()
{
    int rowCounter = 0;
    int columnCounter = 0;

    for (rowCounter = 0; rowCounter <= 8; rowCounter += 1)
    {
        for (columnCounter = 0; columnCounter <= 8; columnCounter += 1)
        {
            pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 9));
            //pane.add(userInputArray[rowCounter][columnCounter]);
            //userInputArray[rowCounter][columnCounter].setColumns(1);
            //userInputArray[rowCounter][columnCounter].setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything commented out will throw the nullpointerexception.

Optimally, my goal is to display the JTextFields on screen, assigning them on the grid.

NullPointerException occurs at `pane.add(...)`

Comment: What is `pane`? Where is it defined? Include more code.

Comment: Apologies, it is the Container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you have created the 2D array to house your fields, you need to instantiate the `JTextField` components in your array.

```
for (int i =0; i < userInputArray.length; i++) {
   for (int j =0; j < userInputArray[0].length; j++) {
      userInputArray[i][j] = new JTextField();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you declare array it is initialized with default values. Default value for `Object` is `null` so you need to instantiate the objects first before using them

```
userInputArray[rowCounter][columnCounter] = new JTextField();
```

So now your code should look like below

```
for (columnCounter = 0; columnCounter <= 8; columnCounter += 1)
    {
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 9));
        userInputArray[rowCounter][columnCounter] = new JTextField();
        pane.add(userInputArray[rowCounter][columnCounter]);
        userInputArray[rowCounter][columnCounter].setColumns(1);
        userInputArray[rowCounter][columnCounter].setVisible(true);
    }
```